# 12.10: ethernet device is not created on boot

Tags: networking, intel, ethernet

I have a problem with my wired interface - an appropriate device for it is just not created at boot. What is strange about it is that it never gets enabled on boot, but is always created after a reboot. This behavior is persistent regardless of whether the carrier is present or not.

Thus the output of some commands after boot is as follows:

- commands like `ls /sys/class/net` or `ifconfig -a` only display *lo* and *wifi* interfaces.
- `lshw -C network` shows the following for the Ethernet adapter:

> ```
>   *-network UNCLAIMED     
>        description: Ethernet controller  
>        product: 82579V Gigabit Network Connection  
>        vendor: Intel Corporation  
>        physical id: 19  
>        bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0  
>        version: 04  
>        width: 32 bits  
>        clock: 33MHz  
>        capabilities: pm msi cap_list
>        configuration: latency=0
>        resources: memory:d0400000-d041ffff memory:d0428000-d0428fff ioport:3020(size=32)
> ```

- `lsmod | grep e1000` shows the module is loaded:

> `e1000e                199273  0` 
>   
>   After a reboot all the above commands report everything is okay and the Ethernet device is present. The only meaningful different I have found is in the output of `dmesg | grep -e eth0 -e e100`:

- after boot (no ethernet interface):

> ```
> [   16.402581] e1000e: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Driver - 2.0.0-k
> [   16.402583] e1000e: Copyright(c) 1999 - 2012 Intel Corporation.
> [   16.402622] e1000e 0000:00:19.0: setting latency timer to 64
> [   16.402678] e1000e 0000:00:19.0: Interrupt Throttling Rate (ints/sec) set to dynamic conservative mode
> [   16.402714] e1000e 0000:00:19.0: irq 46 for MSI/MSI-X
> [   16.409024] eth0: Broadcom BCM4727 802.11 Hybrid Wireless Controller 5.100.82.112
> [   17.394622] e1000e: probe of 0000:00:19.0 failed with error -3
> ```

- after reboot (ethernet interface is present):

> ```
> [   15.208741] e1000e: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Driver - 2.0.0-k
> [   15.208743] e1000e: Copyright(c) 1999 - 2012 Intel Corporation.
> [   15.208777] e1000e 0000:00:19.0: setting latency timer to 64
> [   15.208827] e1000e 0000:00:19.0: Interrupt Throttling Rate (ints/sec) set to dynamic conservative mode
> [   15.208857] e1000e 0000:00:19.0: irq 46 for MSI/MSI-X
> [   15.293928] eth0: Broadcom BCM4727 802.11 Hybrid Wireless Controller 5.100.82.112
> [   15.470050] e1000e 0000:00:19.0: eth0: (PCI Express:2.5GT/s:Width x1) 2c:76:8a:e5:46:79
> [   15.470055] e1000e 0000:00:19.0: eth0: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Connection
> [   15.470103] e1000e 0000:00:19.0: eth0: MAC: 10, PHY: 11, PBA No: FFFFFF-0FF
> [   20.404379] e1000e 0000:00:19.0: irq 46 for MSI/MSI-X
> [   20.508146] e1000e 0000:00:19.0: irq 46 for MSI/MSI-X
> ```

What I have tried so far:

- compiling the latest version of the driver, that is available at Intel Support site;
- installing *sysfsutils* so my */etc/sysfs.conf* looks like this:

  > devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:19.0/enable = 1

but neither has solved the problem.

I have been googling for quite a while now, but have not found much useful information given my problem is so weird. Any ideas will be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found a solution! I pulled the battery out of my laptop for some time (over 30 seconds) and it worked! Thanks to AndresSM's answer here - [Ethernet problems in Ubuntu 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/215966/ethernet-problems-in-ubuntu-12-04).

I don't completely understand reasons behind this, but it seems that it has something to do with Wake-On-LAN and this could be the case:

1. something has disabled the network adapter at some point - could well be Windows (I don't have it installed for a long time already, but I can't recall when the issue started either);
2. then when I power on the laptop, the network card is disabled and Ubuntu does not recognize it at boot;
3. afterwards when I restart Ubuntu, it enables the card while stopping and it is available at start up again. The weird part in that case is why this *enabling* was not persistent.
4. after *completely* powering of the laptop by removing the battery the state of the network card was finally cleared. Note: I did not have Wake-On-LAN enabled at any point of time in BIOS.

The issue outlined above can be usually encountered on dual-boot systems and is covered [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Network_Configuration#Realtek_no_link_.2F_WOL_issue). The link was originally found in that same [thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/215966/ethernet-problems-in-ubuntu-12-04).

If anyone understands this topic better than I do right now, it would be great to learn how this really works. Thanks.